# How to convert excel time without date to pandas dataframe and then plot it?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time

I want to import dataset from excel file to pandas dataframe and then plot it. Dataset includes Date column - which should be convert to pd.datetime and Stopwatch columns - which sould be convert to format: HH:MM:SS or HH:MM or H:MM depends from data (hour could be more than 24 hours and format shouldn't include date). Here are some rows from the data:

```
Date       Stopwatch1 Stopwatch2 Stopwatch3 Timesum
01.08.2019 00:10:05   19:05      0:45       25:01:00
02.08.2019 00:08:00   23:50      0:30       30:30:00
03.08.2019 00:05:00   00:10      0:40      124:00:00
```

Then I want to plot Stopwatch column on y axis with labels in time format (HH:MM) and Date column on x axis. It would be nice if I could specify that for example if time < 06:00 : time = time + 24:00 - what I mean is 00:10 is greater than 23:50 in the Stopwatch2 column so that should be included in the chart.

I try to do:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path, dtype={'Stopwatch1':str, 'Stopwatch2':str, 'Stopwatch3':str})
tmd = pd.to_timedelta(df["Stopwatch1"])
tmd.plot()
```

Plot is working, but the labels on the y axis are numbers. I want to change them to time format(HH:MM).

Comment: The plot works for me on pandas 0.24.1. What is the problem you're getting?

Comment: I try one more time it's working but not in a way it should, because on the y axis labels should be in time format (HH:MM) how can I set them this format?

Comment: There aren't converters for timedeltas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters. This is also really a matplotlib question, you'll want to ask this in that tag.

Comment: Ok, but if there is any way to write this converter? What should it include? Your link isn't working.

Comment: Sorry, should be: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters.html ; timedelta isn't in the list

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the output correctly, but would this be something you are looking for?

I added the Stopwatch1 as a `datetime` so matplotlib `dates` module would understand and then help format it correctly:

```py
df['Stopwatch1'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Stopwatch1"])

from matplotlib import dates as mdates

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['Stopwatch1'])
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M"))
```

[image]

In case you also want the dates as the x-axis, you can set it as the index, so the distance between observations will be based on the date distance.

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df = df.set_index('Date')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index, df['Stopwatch1'])
ax.set_xticks(df.index)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M"))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

[image]

Comment: It's almost what I'm looking for but still I see three problems. Firstly if Stopwatch1 is stored in dataframe as datetime its format contains the current date. Is there any possibility to store it whithout date, just time? Secondly there is problem if I want to plot Stopwatch2. How can I show that for example 00:10 = 24:10 so should be plot above 23:50? Finally there is problem with over 24 hours time like in the Timesum. How can I plot and store it in this format?

Comment: You are right, it will be limited to a day and not to a timedelta. What do you mean that 00:10 should be plot above 23:50? Is it because it's on a subsequent date (and assuming this can be verified by Timesum?

Comment: I mean that I want to specify that: if time in Stopwatch2 is less than 06:00 then time = time + 24:00 (so it should be treated as the next day, like for example 24:10 is greater than 23:50, but I want to format 24:10 as 00:10). Is there a way to do it? By Timesum I mean that time in this column could be greater than 24 hours so I want to plot and store it in format h:mm, hh:mm, hhh:mm ... depends from how large is the number ( for example 2:50, 30:50, 100:50, 2000:00). Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: Everything is possibe @KrzysiekDev. Let me wrap my head around the logic and give it another shot.